# Why can I talk to machines in the local subnet without an entry in the route table for the local subnet?

Tags: networking, routing, static-routes

Running Ubuntu Linux 16.04, connected by Ethernet as 192.168.11.22 with subnet mask /24. The router is at 192.168.11.1.

I was expecting the route table to look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx50
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0 enx50
```

But it is missing the route for the local subnet and looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx50
```

But I am still able to communicate with hosts on on the subnet. How is this possible?

I thought that without a route for the local subnet I wouldn't even be able to communicate with the gateway (192.168.11.1).

Comment: What command are you using to get that routing table? And are you sure you aren't inside some kind of container like OpenVZ?

Comment: It looks like output of `route -n`. What does `ip route` yield?

Comment: Yes, output was from `route -n`.  `ip route` output just shows the same in its own format. Definitely not inside a container - this was directly on my physical Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Routing is **only** needed when an IP packet must be moved from one IP subnetwork to another.

Packets that do not leave the local subnetwork are already at their destination network, making routing unnecessary.

Here's what happens when one computer wants to start a conversation with another node on the same LAN:

1. Node A with IP 10.0.0.1 wants to send a file to Node B at 10.0.0.2.
2. Node A looks at its own IP address and subnet mask (255.255.255.0) and realizes that the IP address 10.0.0.2 **is on the local IP subnetwork**. It therefore needs to send the data directly to that device vs. the default gateway.
3. Node A uses the [ARP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) to get the MAC address of the computer on the LAN with the IP address 10.0.0.2 and sends the data to that node.

Compare this to when the computer needs to communicate with a node on a different IP subnetwork:

1. Node A with IP 10.0.0.1 wants to send a file to Node B at 172.25.0.2.
2. Node A looks at its own IP address and subnet mask (255.255.255.0) and realizes that the IP address 172.25.0.2 is **not** on the local IP subnetwork.  It therefore must send the packet to its default gateway (10.0.0.254).
3. Node A uses the ARP protocol to get the MAC address of the device on the LAN with the IP address 10.0.0.254 (the default gateway) and sends the data to that device.
4. The default gateway (i.e. router) uses its routing table to decide where to send the data next. This process is repeated until the data reaches the destination network.  At *that* point, the process above plays out as the two devices will be on the same IP subnetwork.

#### More Information

- [The OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)
- [OSI Layer 3 - Network Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer)
- [OSI Layer 2 - Data Link Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer)